# Transmission order of lower and higher priority messages in the CAN bus

Tags: can

I would like to ask a theoretical question which is about the CAN bus protocol.

Let's say that we have three nodes, namely A, B and C. First message which has lower priority is sent from A node to C node. The second message which has higher priority is sent from B node to C node during the transmission of first message.

Is the lower priority message going to be processed before high priority message or is the lower priority message going to be stopped?

Comment: Are the nodes A and B on different buses?

Comment: A message is not sent from one node to another-  it is broadcast.  It may be that only one other node *cares* about the content of the message, but all nodes on the bus will check that the message is correctly formed and the CRC is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the CAN spec.

CAN nodes always wait for end of any existing message before attempting to transmit.  Collisions only happen when two nodes decide to do this at the same time.  Once a message is in progress with only a single node transmitting, that message will complete before any other node attempts to transmit.

Comment: There are no collisions even then, CAN is "CSMA/CA" and the bus arbitration procedure makes collisions impossible. If two nodes attempt to send the same message at the same time, the node which sends out a binary zero in the data first will win. And then the other node will attempt to send their message directly after. In case they have the very same data, both send at once and we wouldn't notice it.

Comment: @Lund: This is just semantics of what exactly you call a "collision".  When two nodes send a different message at the same time, they will "collide".  This is resolved as you say.  The node writing the recessive state sees the bus in the opposite state it was trying to write, and backs off.

Comment: Could you suggest a proper CAN spec.?

Comment: @AkifÇelebi Here--> http://esd.cs.ucr.edu/webres/can20.pdf

Answer (score 2):

CAN arbitration is based on the message ID, so if two messages begin transmitting simultaneously, the one with the lowest ID (highest priority) wins and the CAN controller with the higher ID will back off and retry once the bus is available. This is accomplished by monitoring the bus during transmission; since the 0 bit is dominant on the CAN bus, if you transmit a 1 in your ID but read a 0, the conclusion is that some other controller is transmitting with a higher priority.

There is no standards-compliant mechanism for interrupting a message in progress on the bus, so properly behaving controllers will not transmit until the current message is complete.

In summary, if the messages begin transmitting at the same time, the higher-priority message will be received first. If the lower-priority message starts first, then it will be received first. On the receiving node, it is up to the programmer to decide how to handle priorities if a higher priority message is received before related processing is complete for the lower priority message.